# Increase the default timeout of 10 seconds for subprocess in Cloud code of Parse server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, parse-platform

I implemented a Parse cloud function by

```
Parse.Cloud.define('myFoo', function(req, res){
}
```

in my function, I use a sub-process to execute a program and once the result is available, I will call res.success() with my result;

The problem is when I configured my Parse server using the open source Parse project on a fast machine, the result will be returned correctly, but whenever the background service takes longer than 10 seconds to finish, the sub-process will timeout, and my mobile client will receive 'i/o failure with error code 100'.

I did a lot survey online, and I found the clue that before Parse is open sourced, the Parse community won't allow any background service to run for longer than 10 seconds, but now since it is open sourced, is there any way that we can configure **in the source code of Parse server** to allow a slightly longer timeout length, say 15 seconds?

My example code to open the child processs is:

```
const child = exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // may take longer than 10 seconds, and cause the timeout problem.
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    res.success(stdout);
});
```